# In python, how can I test if a path is a symbolic link?

Tags: python

In python, how can I test if a path *is* a symbolic link?  I'm sure it has to do with the [os package](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html), but my searching of the documentation text didn't yield a result.  I'm using version 2.7 at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close, but no cigar. You want the [os.path module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html). Check out [`os.path.islink()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink).